# Simpliest jQuery script is not working in Opera

Tags: javascript, jquery, opera

So I have really simple script written with jQuery. It works well pretty much everywhere except in Opera browser. What's the problem here ?

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    jQuery("input:radio[name=virtuemart_shipmentmethod_id]").change(function() {
        var val = jQuery(this).val();
        if(val == 27 || val == 6) {
            jQuery('.tobehidden').hide();
        }
        else {
            jQuery('.tobehidden').show();
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: it works in opera for me http://jsfiddle.net/9pzynq5s/

Answer (score 0):

try changing

```
 jQuery("input:radio[name=virtuemart_shipmentmethod_id]")
```

to

```
jQuery("input:radio[name='virtuemart_shipmentmethod_id']")
```

Answer (score 0):

try using:

```
jQuery("input:radio[name='virtuemart_shipmentmethod_id']").change(function(){

//do stuff...

})
```